# How to reset max and min range of a range slider on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, range, rangeslider

Here is what I tried, but it did not work:

```
var $slider = jQuery( "#slider" );
$slider.slider("option", "min", min_range);
$slider.slider("option", "max", max_range);
```

Comment: getting any `js` error? otherwise this code should work. can you please post entire js code with HTML.

Comment: No error.. But i fixed it by destroying the slider and then re-initialize it. Thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. When clicked on button i destroyed the slider and then re-initialized it with new range values.

Here is the code:

```
 jQuery("#slider").slider("destroy");
 jQuery("#slider").slider({
            range: true,
            min: new_min_range,
            max: new_max_range,
            values: [ new_min_range, new_max_range ]
});
```